# Windows activation after reinstalling?

Tags: linux, windows-10, windows-activation

Hey Guys I have a Lenovo laptop which came pre installed with a copy of windows 10 Home. For some reasons I need to install Linux in my system, so my doubt is will the windows will be activated if in the future I reinstall the windows? I don't want use dual boot.

Comment: Windows 10 automatically detects the the associated with your device and will automatically activate

Comment: What if the windows is activated with a digital licence?